# Custom npm package and styled-components

Tags: reactjs, npm, styled-components, vite, rollupjs

I have my own npm package that uses Rollup, React and TypeScript. The package contains reusable components styled using styled-components. Everything worked perfectly until I wanted to prepare global styles in the package and also export them. The package builds up and everything runs seemingly fine. Then I have a project that uses Vite with React and TypeScript. If I import components from my package into this project, they are all styled as they should be, but if I import GlobalStyles, the global styles are not applied.

I have this file, which I then export in index.ts:

```js
import {createGlobalStyle} from "styled-components";

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
    html, body, #__next {
      min-height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    html {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    *, *:before, *:after {
      box-sizing: inherit;
    }

    body {
        margin: 0;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 1.4;
    }

    a, a:active {
      color: inherit;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:hover {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
`;

export default GlobalStyle;
```

In my app, which uses Vite in the App component (everything is applied except global styles):

```js
import {HTMLComponentsProvider, Modal, useModal, ModalHeader, ModalContent, FormGrid, css, styled, TextField, GlobalStyle} from "my-super-package";

function App() {
    const modal = useModal();
    return (
        <HTMLComponentsProvider>
            <GlobalStyle />
            <button onClick={modal.open}>open</button>
            <Modal {...modal.props}>
                <ModalHeader>Nazdar</ModalHeader>
                <ModalContent>
                    <StyledFormGrid>
                        <TextField label="Test" ending={"a"} />
                    </StyledFormGrid>
                </ModalContent>
            </Modal>
        </HTMLComponentsProvider>
    );
}

export default App;

const StyledFormGrid = styled(FormGrid)(()=>css`
    
`);
```

I will add that the HTMLComponentsProvider looks like this in the package:

```js
import React, {createElement, ReactNode} from "react";
import {HTMLComponentsContextType} from "./types";
import HTMLComponentsContext from "./HTMLComponentsContext";
import {THEME} from "../styles";
import {ThemeProvider} from "styled-components";

export interface HTMLComponentsProviderProps extends HTMLComponentsContextType {
    children: ReactNode;
}

const HTMLComponentsProvider = (
    {
        children,
        globalStyles,
        components,
        ...value
    }: HTMLComponentsProviderProps
) => {
    const theme = {...THEME, ...value};
    return (
        <HTMLComponentsContext.Provider value={{...theme, components}}>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                {children}
            </ThemeProvider>
        </HTMLComponentsContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default HTMLComponentsProvider;
```

My Rollup config:

```js
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import terser from '@rollup/plugin-terser';
import external from 'rollup-plugin-node-externals';
import dts from 'rollup-plugin-dts';
import packageJson from './package.json' assert { type: "json" };

export default [
    {
        input: 'src/index.ts',
        output: [
            {
                file: packageJson.main,
                format: 'cjs',
                sourcemap: true,
                name: 'react-lib'
            },
            {
                file: packageJson.module,
                format: 'esm',
                sourcemap: true
            }
        ],
        plugins: [
            external({devDeps: true, deps: false}),
            resolve(),
            commonjs(),
            typescript({ tsconfig: './tsconfig.json' }),
            terser()
        ]
    },
    {
        input: 'lib/esm/types/index.d.ts',
        output: [{ file: 'lib/index.d.ts', format: "esm" }],
        plugins: [dts()],
    }
]
```

I'm using styled-components 5.3.10 and Vite 4.3.2. Thank you very much for any advice, I will add more information if necessary. If I attach the global styles file directly to the project (I don't use a package), the styles will show up.